# How can I give out a compiler error if a function parameter is too big?

Tags: avr-gcc

I am using microchip studio and I am programming a function to communicate between up to 4 Atmega microcontrollers. I know there are already in built options like I2C, but I want to program something myself to learn. I have a function:

```
void sendComms(uint8_t address, uint8_t data);
```

Is it possible to stop the program from compiling and give out an error if the address parameter entered is larger than 4? Right now i just have: `if(address>4){return;}`

I have not tried anything because I don't have any ideas.

Comment: What language are you using? C? C++?

Comment: Function arguments don't exist until runtime. If you want the compiler to help you with that, you'll need to express `address` as something other than a function argument. Will `address` actually always be a compile-time constant?